# Why date_joined empty?

Tags: django, django-models

"Date_joined This field is required" error message when i try to update user profile.Why is the value not being recorded automatically? Where are my mistakes?

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=210, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=False,
                                    max_length=20,
                                    validators=[validate_phone_number],
                                    default="+38(098)000-0000")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='accounts')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        image = Image.open(self.image)
        image.thumbnail((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(self.image.path)
```

view.py

```
class AccountRegistrationView(CreateView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'registration.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
        form_class = AccountRegistrationForm
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            result = super().form_valid(form)
            messages.success(self.request, 'User registered successfully')
            return result
```

forms.py

```
class AccountRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'register__input'
            })
```

My template registration.html When displaying as_p, I see the whole form and the selection of is_staff although it shouldn't be there in theory

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
       <section class="register">
            <div class="register__block">
                <form class="register__form" method="post">
                    <div class="register__title">
                        Регистрация
                    </div>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.username.errors}}
                    <div class="register__item">
                        {{form.username}}

                        <span class="register__focus">
                        </span>
                        <span class="register__item--title">
                            Nickname
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.email.errors}}
                    <div class="register__item">
                        {{form.email}}
                        <span class="register__focus">
                        </span>
                        <span class="register__item--title">
                            E-mail
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.password1.errors}}
                    <div class="register__item">
                        {{form.password1}}
                        <span class="register__focus">
                        </span>
                        <span class="register__item--title">
                            Пароль
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.password2.errors}}
                    <div class="register__item">
                        {{form.password2}}
                        <span class="register__focus">
                        </span>
                        <span class="register__item--title">
                            Повтороите пароль
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="register__btn">
                        Зарегистрироваться
                    </button>
                    <div class="register__text">
                        У Вас уже есть аккаунт? <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Войти</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
            </div>
       </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should take all the fields i.e, fields = ––all–– something like that

Comment: You say _"when i try to update user profile"_. Did you mean create? Because that is the code you show us. Also add the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: @Irfanwani i did it and i got the same error but when registering

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I made the user's recommendation above and I got the same error when registering, my template is not just the output {{form}}, but the output of individual fields

Comment: @Alexander Please add your template and the **full stack trace** of the error you get to the question.

Comment: @Alexander Do you have any pending migrations?

Comment: @Mugoma No migrations to apply.